# How to export to shapefile. Shapelib129.dll is missing

Tags: oracle, dll, spatial

I am trying to use SDO2SHP.exe in order to export some spatial data from Oracle for use later with shp2pgsql in order to import it to a postgresql database. I receive the error:

```
"The program can't start because shapelib129.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."
```

Has anyone come across this problem before? If so what is the solution. The obvious thing would be to download the dll from somewhere however I cannot seem to find it. There is not the option to install the program as it is simply an executable file.

P.S. If anyone could add a custom tag I would appreciate the sdo2shp tag being added. Apparently it hasnt been used before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file shapelib129.dll can be found in the following location:

```
\sdo2shp\Libs\SHAPELIB\Delphi\
```

This file must then be copied into the same directory as your SDO2Shp.exe executable file in order to allow it to work.